# Unhandled and Uncatchable System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, access-violation

While stress testing our application we always seem to suffer a catastrophic AccessViolationException after around 10-12 hours of use.

Using WinDbg to locate the source I see that it seems to originate from the native form's message loop. It would be great if someone would confirm my suspicion so I include a full stack trace with parameters. I have also taken a full stack trace if anyone needs more information.

Thanks in advance!

> 0:000> !CLRStack -p OS Thread Id: 0x748 (0) ESP       EIP
>   0012d44c 7c90e514 [InlinedCallFrame: 0012d44c]
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.WaitMessage() 0012d448
>   7b1d8ed8
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32,
>   Int32, Int32)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x015fe94c
>           dwComponentID = 
>           reason = 0x00000004
>           pvLoopData = 0x00000000
>
> 0012d4e4 7b1d89c7
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153d9ec
>           reason = 0x00000004
>           context = 0x0226ec58
>
> 0012d538 7b1d8811
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           reason = 
>           context =
>
> 0012d568 7b6ede47
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           form =
>
> 0012d57c 7b7225cb
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x02265860
>           owner =
>
> 0012d608 7b7227e3 System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this =
>
> 0012d60c 7b6eefa2
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153d9ec
>           t = 0x02265600
>
> 0012d648 7b6f7936
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(System.Exception)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           e =
>
> 0012d654 7b6fa3bc
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           e =
>
> 0012d658 7b1c8502 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01a9c930
>           hWnd = 
>           msg = 0x00000002
>           wparam = 
>           lparam =
>
> 0012e880 003c25e4 [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0012e880]
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)
>   0012e898 7b19ec50
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DestroyWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           hWnd =
>
> 0012e8a8 7b19eb5a System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DestroyHandle()
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01a96d08
>
> 0012e8ec 7b1b9050 System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01a967a8
>
> 0012e8f0 7b7226bc [InlinedCallFrame: 0012e8f0]  0012ea04 7b7227e3
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this =
>
> 0012ea08 04bf3a7b
>   Workstation.FrontScreenForm.HandleNewEvent(GroupsRow, Int16, Int64)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153b26c
>           Group = 0x01a8de34
>           EventTypeID = 0x00000003
>           previousEventID = 0xffffffff
>
> 0012ec50 04bf344f
>   Workstation.FrontScreenForm.HandleNewEvent(GroupsRow, Int16)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153b26c
>           Group = 0x01a8de34
>           EventTypeID = 0x00000003
>
> 0012ec64 04b21ac4
>   Workstation.FrontScreenForm.btnSiteCheck_Click(System.Object,
>   System.EventArgs)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153b26c
>           sender = 0x01546a44
>           e = 0x0153e990
>
> 0012ecd4 7b194180
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           e =
>
> 0012ecec 7b18f56a
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           e =
>
> 0012ecfc 7b734429
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnKeyUp(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01546a44
>           kevent = 0x01a914c0
>
> 0012ed0c 7b6f5bf1
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01546a44
>           m = 0x0012ee44
>
> 0012ed5c 7b6f5c95
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           m =
>
> 0012ed6c 7b6f7381
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01546a44
>           m = 0x0012ee44
>
> 0012ed7c 7ba2a0ee
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           m =
>
> 0012ed80 7b1c2626 [InlinedCallFrame: 0012ed80]  0012ee18 7b1c25a0
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           m =
>
> 0012ee24 7b1c8690
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           m =
>
> 0012ee2c 7b1c8611
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message
>   ByRef)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           m =
>
> 0012ee40 7b1c84ea System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x01546b14
>           hWnd = 
>           msg = 0x00000101
>           wparam = 
>           lparam =
>
> 0012f220 003c25e4 [NDirectMethodFrameStandalone: 0012f220]
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
>   0012f230 7b1d8d5e
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32,
>   Int32, Int32)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x015fe94c
>           dwComponentID = 
>           reason = 0xffffffff
>           pvLoopData = 0x00000000
>
> 0012f2cc 7b1d89c7
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 0x0153d9ec
>           reason = 0xffffffff
>           context = 0x015fdcd4
>
> 0012f320 7b1d8811
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           this = 
>           reason = 
>           context =
>
> 0012f350 7b195921
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
>       PARAMETERS:
>           mainForm =
>
> 0012f364 00f809df Workstation.Program.Main() 0012f688 79e71b4c
>   [GCFrame: 0012f688]

Comment: Hmm, is `Workstation.FrontScreenForm` one of yours? Your app seems to be in a ShowDialog but a lot of code below it, any calls to DoEvents() ?

Comment: Looks to me like somebody pressed the `btnSiteCheck` button, and the handler tried to show a new dialog. Then things went bad. The exception appears to have occurred in the dialog's message loop, but it was probably caused by destroying the dialog handle. I would suggest that you look into what's happening in that button click method.

Comment: The source you found is very likely to be a victim. Access violation is typically caused by a problematic module who corrupts other modules' memory locations, and make them victims. You need to carefully analyze the memory space and follow best practices (for example, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/09/net-crash-managed-heap-corruption-calling-unmanaged-code.aspx) Since it requires too much experience, you may try to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to consult experienced Microsoft support guys.

Answer (score 0):

An access violation exception will not usually come from managed code, it means that your OS decided the process has done something bad (trying to access/change memory where it shouldn't) and should be terminated. 
when you catch the exception with windbg (and take the dump) it is already too late.

some options:

- Use debugdiag to take a crash dump (this will get a dump in the right place, before the exception was thrown and the process started to deconstruct) [Capturing crash dumps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx), [Download DebugDiag 1.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798)
- look at the task manager after the process has run for a while and is expected to fail, (use select columns) check the GDI, handles, threads,User objects - these are all tracked resources and have limits the OS upholds, if one of them is high (in the thousands) this might be a problem.
- look at your code, check any points that use unmanaged objcts and verify they are correctly disposed. (using COMobjects is the most common way to access unmanaged resources and these can cause an access violation, as they use OS mem allocations directly)